# The BOOK proof of the quadratic reciprocity law - need explanation about prime field of finite field

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

There is a sentence:

Let $p$ and $q$ be different odd primes, and consider the finite field $F$ with $q^{p-1}$ elements. Its prime field is $\mathbb{Z}_q$, whence $qa=0$ for any $a\in F$.

Why is it so? Thank you.

Comment: Which part are you asking about? Why the prime field looks like that, or why it follows that the characteristic of the field is $q$?

Comment: Both, really. :)

Comment: Have you seen the theorem that the characteristic of a field is always a prime?

Comment: Yes. I see where you're going... Why, then, the prime field is $\mathbb{Z}_q$, not, say, $\mathbb{Z}_2$? Is it because if we look at $F$ as an additive group, then the order of subgroup should divide the order of group, so the minimal non-trivial subgroup would be of order $q$, because the order of $F$ is $q^{p-1}$?

Comment: Yes, precisely.